# How to Generate Random names for Images while storing in Internal Memory?

Tags: android, sqlite

The Android Application which I am developing is basically a shopping application, which has a Cart option, where user can add items.

The Items has Image, Name, Price etc..

I get all these data from server.

When user click "Add to Cart " option then a sqlite database is created  where I store the name, price and image path.

Basically Imgaes are stored in the internal memory when add to cart is clicked and only image path is stored in the database.

**Problem:**

To store images in the internal memory I use the below code where I will give the file name myself (In this case I give file name as **profile.jpg**).

SaveToMemory:

```
 private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
     directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();

}
```

LoadFromMemory:

```
private Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

    try {
        File f=new File(path, "");
        f.canRead();
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        return b;


    }
```

If I do so, latest image is overridden by the previous image. Iam not able to store multiple images in the internal memory.

For Example If I add two items inside the cart I dont know how to store those two images and get it.

**Aim**

Need to store any number of images with random file name in the internal memory

Store the file name in sqlite database.

Retrieve it back to display in Imageview.

Any help would be greatly thankfull.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
mypath=new File(directory,System.currentTimeMillis()+"_profile.jpg");
```

instead of

```
mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");
```

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will returns the current time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC. so it is different each time

Answer (score 5):

You can use [UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html)

```
new File(directory,"profile_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");
```

it would be

> profile_e85c5115-eea6-4b0d-98e3-9e09c2d505b3.jpg

Comment: you can trim it to be more friendly, UUID.randomUUID().toString().subString(0,5);

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date().toString()` instead of `"profile.jpg"`